# Can't make a toast appear when using doInBackground (AsyncTask)

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask, toast

i'm trying to post on facebook so i'm uising the following code. It works well, but I can't seem to post a simple confirmation toast.

```
private class FacebookPoster extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object>
    {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... message)
        {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message[0]);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            parameters.putString("link", ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.rateLink));
            parameters.putString("picture", ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.linkIconPicture));
            Log.d("ERRRR", "set params");
            try
            {
                facebook.request("me");
                String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false"))
                {
                    return "Blank response.";

                }
                else
                {
                    return "Message posted to your facebook wall!";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Failed to post to wall!";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            showToast(values);

        }
    }
```

showToast function

```
private void showToast(Object message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I think the onProgressUpdate is not called. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onProgressUpdate` is made for updating your progress-bar for example when the code is still running, and you need to call `onProgressUpdate` manual, using the `publishProgress` method.

You are returning a string (Object) in the `doInBackground` method. This string will be send to the `onPostExecute` method.

So what you should do is remove the `onProgressUpdate` method, and override the `onPostExecute` method and put the Toast code inside it.

**Note:** `onProgressUpdate` and `publishProgress` should only be used for updating progress while the background task is still running, not for showing the final result. For the final result you use the `onPostExecute` method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse onProgressUpdate is not being called.

You have to call it yourself in your doInBackground:

```
publishProgress(<somenumber>);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `publishProgress()` inside your `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onPostExecute()` method and move the call to `showToast()` to that method.

It looks like your `onProgressUpdate()` is not being called at all. And in your scenario, you'd rather show a toast after `doInBackground()` finishes!